# What is the best operating system for home server?

Tags: operating-system, server, webserver

Sorry for repeating this question, but wanted to get the latest/updated news in this issue. I am planning on running my own home server so that I can access my files and webpages over the internet. Then I got stuck on the basic problem, which operating system to use. The options that I have in mind are FreeBSD and Ubuntu Server. Both look the same to me as a beginner, but can you guys give me a deep view on what I should choose to run my server on (I am open to other suggestions as well)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to go with the CentOS, You can easily install/upgrade any packages which you want on your server.